# C# Trying to get all fields from a PDF using ITextSharp returns 0 fields

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, xsl-fo

I have a PDF document that was obtained by converting a XSL-FO document to PDF using a XSL-FO to PDF render engine called [fonet](https://fonet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Home).

To convert XSL-FO document to PDF I did as explained [here](https://fonet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Section%201%3A%20Hello%20World%21%20Example&referringTitle=Getting%20Started).

Now, I am trying to get all the fields in the PDF file using [ITextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). To do this I proceed as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041883/how-do-i-enumerate-all-the-fields-in-a-pdf-file-in-itextsharp). However, in line af.Fields it returns 0 fields. Why?

Comment: I very much doubt that fonet supports fields.

Comment: There are XSL FO engines that support PDFForms, possibly you need to look into one that can create PDF Forms

Answer (score 0):

fonet **does not** support forms.
If you were to search through their documentation for the term 'form' you would find exactly 1 match.

In the sentence:

> A variety of overloaded forms of Render are available.

If however you are already using iText, then why not simply use a tool like apache XSLT to convert your XSL-FO into HTML? Then you can use pdfHTML which converts HTML to PDF.

Comment: Read [this chapter from the official documentation](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/7-creating-pdf-invoices-comfort) to discover a Java example of what Joris is explaining.

Comment: Or choose an XSL FO engine that supports PDF Forms and not try a strange FO to HTML conversion which would still be missing form fields

Comment: @KevinBrown Do you know any XSL FO engine to convert to PDF that supports PDF Forms and free?